# libgdx throws exception on Mac, couldn't load shared library libgdx-controllers-desktop.dylib

Tags: java, macos, libgdx

I have a problem with the libgdx.
It Says:

```
Couldn't load shared library 'libgdx-controllers-desktop.dylib' for target: Mac OS X, 32-bit
```

Do anyone have a suggestion?

Full Exception:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Error creating controller manager: com.badlogic.gdx.controllers.desktop.DesktopControllerManager
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:113)
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Error creating controller manager: com.badlogic.gdx.controllers.desktop.DesktopControllerManager
    at com.badlogic.gdx.controllers.Controllers.initialize(Controllers.java:101)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.controllers.Controllers.getControllers(Controllers.java:47)
    at de.datpixelstudio.canopus.states.GameState.init(GameState.java:50)
    at de.datpixelstudio.statebasedgame.StateBasedGame.enterState(StateBasedGame.java:97)
    at de.datpixelstudio.statebasedgame.State.enterState(State.java:54)
    at de.datpixelstudio.statebasedgame.InputHandlerMain.keyDown(InputHandlerMain.java:41)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.InputMultiplexer.keyDown(InputMultiplexer.java:70)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglInput.processEvents(LwjglInput.java:277)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:187)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:110)
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load shared library 'libgdx-controllers-desktop.dylib' for target: Mac OS X, 32-bit
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SharedLibraryLoader.load(SharedLibraryLoader.java:104)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.controllers.desktop.DesktopControllerManager.<init>(DesktopControllerManager.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.controllers.Controllers.initialize(Controllers.java:99)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SharedLibraryLoader.load(SharedLibraryLoader.java:102)
    ... 17 more
```

its the nightly version 01/12/2013

Comment: The "libgdx-controllers-desktop.dylib" should be in the gdx-controllers-desktop-natives.jar is that on your classpath?  The SharedLibraryLoader has some new "extraction" code (see https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/SharedLibraryLoader.java) that may be causing problems on your system ...

Comment: That was the problem :) Forgot to put the  gdx-controllers-desktop-natives.jar in. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, that caused the problem. I forgot to take the  gdx-controllers-desktop-natives.jar in.