# libGDX applet on Mac OS X can't load libgdx.dylib

Tags: java, applet, libgdx, lwjgl

I have followed http://www.thesecretpie.com/2011/05/being-like-minecraft-or-how-to-run-your.html.

Using Mac OS X, Mountain Lion, on both Firefox and Safari, I get this:

```
This occurred while 'Switching applet'
Couldn't load shared library 'libgdx.dylib' for target: Mac OS X, 32-bit
com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load shared library 'libgdx.dylib' for target: Mac OS X, 32-bit
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SharedLibraryLoader.load(SharedLibraryLoader.java:110)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxNativesLoader.load(GdxNativesLoader.java:34)
........
........
........
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Unable to read file for extraction: libgdx.dylib
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SharedLibraryLoader.readFile(SharedLibraryLoader.java:119)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SharedLibraryLoader.loadFile(SharedLibraryLoader.java:231)
```

Additionally, I got some manifest-related messages. I'm not sure if these are relevant:

```
Missing Application-Name: manifest attribute for: http://example.com/applet/lwjgl_util_applet.jar
Missing Permissions manifest attribute for: http://example.com/applet/lwjgl_util_applet.jar
Missing Codebase manifest attribute for: http://example.com/applet/lwjgl_util_applet.jar
Missing Application-Name: manifest attribute for: http://example.com/applet/lwjgl_util_applet.jar
Missing Permissions manifest attribute for: http://example.com/applet/lwjgl_util_applet.jar
Missing Codebase manifest attribute for: http://example.com/lwjgl_util_applet.jar
```

---

Updating Java doesn't quite solve this either.

Now then, I found this question: [libgdx throws exception on Mac, couldn't load shared library libgdx-controllers-desktop.dylib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14298399/libgdx-throws-exception-on-mac-couldnt-load-shared-library-libgdx-controllers) which seems to address pretty much the same problem I am having. However, the solution was

> I forgot to take the gdx-controllers-desktop-natives.jar in.

I grabbed such file and placed it in my `/applet` folder, and also went to the `index.html` file and added `gdx-controllers-desktop-natives.jar` to the `al_jars` attribute, but it didn't work.

I also added `gdx-controllers-desktop-natives.jar` as an external JAR to my project before exporting it with Eclipse, but still no luck.

So I guess that their solution is not working for me. What may be causing this problem?

- I am using the latest libGDX version.
- I am using version `2.7.1` of the `lwjgl_util_applet.jar` because that's the one used in the guide, but also because the latest one doesn't work for me ([ClassNotFound for AppletLoader when exporting a libGDX applet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20541236/555690)).

Comment: Is the applet deployed using JWS/JNLP?

Answer (score 0):

The error

```
Couldn't load shared library 'libgdx.dylib' for target: Mac OS X, 32-bit
```

means that the Libgdx Java code cannot find the Libgdx native code it needs for the current platform (which it thinks is "Mac OS X, 32-bit").

The manifest issues are not related to this problem (as those are about the LWJGL layer, not Libgdx).

The question you linked is very similar, except that you are missing the native library for the *core Libgdx library*, and that question is about the missing native library for the *Libgdx controllers library* (one of the Libgdx extensions).  You need to make sure the core libgdx natives .jar is included in your applet.  Specifically, you need to make sure there is a .jar file that contains the file "libgdx.dylib" included in your applet.